# Excel Copy and Pasting data into multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel question that comes in two parts: Firstly, if I would like to copy data from one worksheet to another where Sheet 1 has:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

and for Sheet 2 I want every cell to repeat thrice such that when I paste the previous five cells into Sheet 2, each cell appears thrice:

```
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C   
C
D
D
D
E
E
E
```

How do I do that? I personally do now know of any formula or function that can let me do that so really looking forward to your advice.

Once that is done, is there a way to write it up using VBA? I am very very new to VBA and was just thinking if it is possible. Otherwise, I will just record a macro. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With data in Sheet1 like:

[image]

In Sheet2, cell **A1** enter:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

*( if you want 4 copies of each data item, use **4** in the formula)*

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! It definitely does the job. However, I have to manually drag the formula down the column until the last row, which is 3 times of the original array length. Is there a way to auto-fill down the column only up till the last row of Sheet 2 at 3 times of the original array length?

Comment: So for example, if the last row in Sheet 1 is A7 and we want each cell to repeat 3 times, the last row in Sheet 2 is A21. How do we autofill down up till  only A21? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: @LovetoLearn  We would need to check the formula result against 0 and return blank instead ??

Answer (score 0):

a VBA way:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim data As Variant, datum As Variant
    Dim iDatum As Long, nTimes As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet 1") '<--| reference your "source" worksheet (change "Sheet 1" to your actual "source" sheet name
        data = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value) '<--| store its column A cells values from row 1 down to last not empty one into an array
    End With

    nTimes = 3 '<--| set how many times you want to copy the same value
    With Worksheets("Sheet 2") '<--| reference your "target" worksheet (change "Sheet 2" to your actual "target" sheet name
        .Range("A1").Resize(nTimes) = data(LBound(data)) '<--| write 1st 'data' array value 'nTimes' from its cell A1 down
        For iDatum = LBound(data) + 1 To UBound(data) '<--| loop through other 'data' array values
            .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(nTimes) = data(iDatum) '<--| write them 'nTimes' from first empty row after last not empty one down
        Next iDatum
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason, Excel says it is out of range. Thank you though.

Comment: this line:

.Range("A1").Resize(nTimes) = data(LBound(data))

Also, so if my sheet 1 starts from A2 but sheet 2 starts from A7. in the example you gave, do i replace the first A1 with A2 and the second A1 with A7?

Comment: Yes. My example assumed both sheets started from A1.

Comment: did you try my code with those substitutions you argued and I confirmed you?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I did the old-fashioned way of doing it step by step and it worked:

```
LastRow = have.Cells(have.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim p As Long
pp = 3
For p = 1 To LastRow
    want.Range("A" & pp) = have.Range("A" & p).Value
    pp = pp + 1
    want.Range("A" & pp) = have.Range("A" & p).Value
    pp = pp + 1
    want.Range("A" & pp) = have.Range("A" & p).Value
    pp = pp + 1
Next p
```

Comment: If you really "love to learn", you have to abandon this way (which is not "old fashioned" but "poorly performing") and try and learn from other people